Installing via intunewin package - specifc program with powershell script
My company has recently gone 100% virtual and need a way to install N-Able's TakeControl via Intune through an .intunewin package. The script will execute per device, while installing program.
Here's our setup:
Our employees are using Dell Optiplex 7000 MFF as Thin Clients into a W365 CPC. Whenever an employee has a problem, we've been using Quick Assist. However, this option doesn't show the local PC settings.
I have installed the N-Able TakeControl onto a Thin Client test unit I have, however, there is a pop-up at the end that needs to be confirmed with either yes or no. In order for this application to fully install, the Yes option must be clicked.
Here is what I have already written, as my powershell scripting ins't the best. If there is a simpler way to do this, I'm open to all suggestions.
# Self-elevate the script if required
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
 
{   
    $arguments = "&amp; '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
    Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
    Break
}

# Verify C:\programdata\logs
if (!(test-path "C:\programdata\logs")) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -path "C:\programdata\logs" -force
}

# Set variables
$ScriptRoot = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

# Install BAManagement
Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/i $ScriptRoot\BAManagement.msi /qn /l C:\programdata\logs\InstallBAMmanagement.log"

I have tested the script on my test machine, program installs but still prompts to select either Yes or No. Problem I have, all our employees are remote and this needs to be installed without user intervention. How do I write the installation script to select Yes on first run?
I found this post from 11 years ago, MSIEXEC not installing an MSI setup if /QUIET parameter is used to suppress the UI, but this doesn't help my issue of being able to select Yes once the installation completes.
